# Проблема с заголовком фида rss

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

Сделал код импорта новостей rss, используя `SimpleXmlElement`, с последующим добавлением новостей в Посты (**wordpress**). Все работает так, как нужно, но за исключением заголовков. В коде я делаю проверку на существование фида в постах по заголовку:

```
if(!post_exists($title)) {
   wp_insert_post($feed_post);
} else {}
```

Проблема в том, что в посты добавляется всего половина фидов, либо чуть более, но не все 40 фидов. Я пробовал использовать `html_entity_decode()` для заголовка, но это не помогло.
Если я убираю пробелы путем `preg_replace("/\s/", "", &title)`, или же заменяю на `-` `preg_replace("/\s/", "-", &title)`, то в посты добавляются все 40 фидов, и это работает хорошо, но заголовок теперь без пробелов, или с `-`. Но так быть не должно. И пробелы нужно сохранить.

Какая-то проблема с пробелами. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте, что можно сделать? Как это решить?

Я так же пытался выявить невидимые символы в тексте заголовков. Но все чисто. Странно. Может какая-то особенность в работе `post_exists()`?

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Вот больше кода:

```
foreach (get_field('feed_sources', 'option') as $feed_source) {
        $feeds = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents($feed_source['resource_link'], false, $context));
        foreach ($feeds->channel->item as $feed) {
            $title = preg_replace("/\s/", "-", html_entity_decode($feed->title));
            $content = $feed->children($feed->getNamespaces(true)['content'])->encoded;
            $date = date('n-j-Y', strtotime($feed->pubDate));
            $img = trim((string)$feed->children($feed->getNamespaces(true)['media'])->content->attributes()->url);
            $feed_post = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => $content,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',     
            );
            if(!post_exists($title)) {
                wp_insert_post($feed_post);
            } else {}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не надо ставить в title поста уже очищенный `$title`. Используйте `$feed->title`.

```
'post_title'    => $title,
```

Вот полный код, который должен работать:

```
foreach ( get_field( 'feed_sources', 'option' ) as $feed_source ) {
    $feeds = new SimpleXmlElement( file_get_contents( $feed_source['resource_link'], false, $context ) );
    foreach ( $feeds->channel->item as $feed ) {
        $title     = preg_replace( '/\s/', '-', $feed->title );
        $content   = $feed->children( $feed->getNamespaces( true )['content'] )->encoded;
        $date      = date( 'n-j-Y', strtotime( $feed->pubDate ) );
        $img       = trim( (string) $feed->children( $feed->getNamespaces( true )['media'] )->content->attributes()->url );
        $feed_post = [
            'post_title'   => $feed->title,
            'post_content' => $content,
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
        ];
        if ( ! post_exists( $title ) ) {
            wp_insert_post( $feed_post );
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Загружается только 14 из 40

Comment: Вы же написали `или же заменяю на - preg_replace("/\s/", "-", &title), то в посты добавляются все 40 фидов,`/ Смотрите мой код, там ровно это сделано.